Macro efficiency vs. Progress Bar
I have 2 macros where the first macro asks how many rows I wish to insert which then calls my second macro below. This setup works great, however, if I wish to add 100 rows it takes some time to complete and gives the user an impression that excel is broken.
I was planning to add a progress bar but before I attempt that functionality, I was wondering if there's a better way to make my second macro more efficient. I'm no expert but I don't feel I'm asking too much of my macro to make it run slow.  Note:  I could be way off base, but in my head I think this should run in seconds vs. a few minutes.
Any insight is appreciated.
Sub vdc_InsertRow_Inventory()


'Adds new row
    Worksheets("INVENTORY").Range("B8").EntireRow.Insert
    
'Clears all combo boxes back to default
    Worksheets("INVENTORY").Range("B5:AI5").Select
    Selection.ClearContents

'Add default value to PRICING fields
    Worksheets("INVENTORY").Range("C8").Value = "Not Started"
    

'Add default value to EXPENSES fields
    Worksheets("INVENTORY").Range("P8").Formula = "=XLOOKUP(1,(LOOKUP2!$B$7:$B$100=H8) * (LOOKUP2!$C$7:$C$100=I8) * (LOOKUP2!$D$7:$D$100=J8) * (LOOKUP2!$E$7:$E$100=K8),LOOKUP2!$H$7:$H$100,0)"
    Worksheets("INVENTORY").Range("Q8").Formula = "=SUPPLIES!$E$12"
    
'Add default value to SHIPPING fields
    Worksheets("INVENTORY").Range("S8").Formula = "=XLOOKUP($R8, SHIP!$H$7:$H$938, SHIP!$I$7:$I$938,"""")"
    Worksheets("INVENTORY").Range("U8").Formula = "=XLOOKUP($T8, SHIP!$C$7:$C$41, SHIP!$F$7:$F$41,"""")"


'Add default value to FEES fields
    Worksheets("INVENTORY").Range("X8").Formula = "=FEES!$C$4*($D8+$E8+$F8)"
    Worksheets("INVENTORY").Range("Y8").Formula = "=IF($C8=""Not Started"",0,IF([@Price]+[@Ship]>9.99,FEES!$C$6,FEES!$C$5))"
    Worksheets("INVENTORY").Range("Z8").Formula = "=IF(COUNTIF($C23:$C$52,""Active"")>250,FEES!$C$8,FEES!$C$7)"
    Worksheets("INVENTORY").Range("AB8").Formula = "=$F8"
     
'Add default value to GRADING fields
    Worksheets("INVENTORY").Range("AF8").Formula = "=IF(AC8>0,GRADING!$D$15,0)"
     
'Scroll screen back to starting range in worksheet
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 1
    Range("B8").Select
    
End Sub


Are you adding one row at a time?  Most likely that's the source of your slowness.  Can you also show the other code which calls vdc_InsertRow_Inventory?

Worksheets("INVENTORY").Range("B8").Resize(n).EntireRow.Insert will insert n rows.  Populate the formulas like (eg) Worksheets("INVENTORY").Range("Q8").Resize(n).Formula = "=SUPPLIES!$E$12"   Put Calculation to manual while inserting the formulas.

Try this out:
Sub vdc_InsertRow_Multiple() 
    Dim numrow 
    numrow = Application.InputBox("How many rows would you like this add?", _
                               "Enter a number", , , , , , 1) 
    If IsNumeric(numrow) Then vdc_InsertRow_Inventory CLng(numrow)
End Sub

'Insert `numRows` rows on INVENTORY and populate formulas
Sub vdc_InsertRow_Inventory(numRows As Long)

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("INVENTORY")
    
    ws.Range("B5:AI5").ClearContents 'Clear combo boxes back to default
    
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual 'turn off automatic calculation
    ws.Range("B8").Resize(numRows).EntireRow.Insert
    With ws.Rows(8).Resize(numRows)
        .Columns("C").Value = "Not Started" 'Add default value to PRICING fields
        .Columns("P").Formula = "=XLOOKUP(1,(LOOKUP2!$B$7:$B$100=H8) * " & _
                                "(LOOKUP2!$C$7:$C$100=I8) * (LOOKUP2!$D$7:$D$100=J8) * " & _
                                "(LOOKUP2!$E$7:$E$100=K8),LOOKUP2!$H$7:$H$100,0)" 'EXPENSES fields
        .Columns("Q").Formula = "=SUPPLIES!$E$12"
        .Columns("S").Formula = "=XLOOKUP($R8, SHIP!$H$7:$H$938, SHIP!$I$7:$I$938,"""")" 'SHIPPING fields
        .Columns("U").Formula = "=XLOOKUP($T8, SHIP!$C$7:$C$41, SHIP!$F$7:$F$41,"""")"
        .Columns("X").Formula = "=FEES!$C$4*($D8+$E8+$F8)" 'FEES
        .Columns("Y").Formula = "=IF($C8=""Not Started"",0,IF([@Price]+[@Ship]>9.99,FEES!$C$6,FEES!$C$5))"
        .Columns("Z").Formula = "=IF(COUNTIF($C23:$C$52,""Active"")>250,FEES!$C$8,FEES!$C$7)"
        .Columns("AB").Formula = "=$F8"
        .Columns("AF").Formula = "=IF(AC8>0,GRADING!$D$15,0)" 'GRADING fields
    End With
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic 'reset to auto
    
    ws.Select
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 1
    ws.Range("B8").Select
    
End Sub


THIS CODE WORKED PERFECTLY!!!!  How would I update Sub Tester to get a pop-up to insert my row count?  I've included that code below:
Sub vdc_InsertRow_Multiple()

Dim runmacro
runmacro = Application.InputBox("How many rows would you like this add?", "Enter a number", , , , , , 1)

If IsNumeric(numrow) Then

For i = 1 To runmacro

Call vdc_InsertRow_Inventory

Next i
End If
End Sub


If IsNumeric(numrow) Then  vdc_InsertRow_Inventory numrow

I tried adding your suggestion be get a byref argument type mismatch. I posted code below and commented out my original lines.
Sub Tester()
    'vdc_InsertRow_Invent 10  'insert 10 rows (for example)
    Dim runmacro
       
    runmacro = Application.InputBox("How many rows would you like this add?", "Enter a number", , , , , , 1)

    'If IsNumeric(numrow) Then
    If IsNumeric(numrow) Then vdc_InsertRow_Invent numrow
    'For i = 1 To runmacro

    'Call vdc_InsertRow_Invent

    'Next i
    End If
End Sub


Sorry should have been vdc_InsertRow_Inventory CLng(numrow)

Now getting VBA runtime error 1004 in vdc_InsertRow_Inventory macro
'Insert `numRows` rows on INVENTORY and populate formulas
Sub vdc_InsertRow_Inventory(numRows As Long)
    Dim ws As Worksheet
        Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("INVENTORY")
        ws.Range("B5:AI5").ClearContents 'Clear combo boxes back to default
    
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual 'turn off automatic calculation
   ws.Range("B8").Resize(numRows).EntireRow.Insert 'ERROR OUT HERE
    With ws.Rows(8).Resize(numRows)
'''

What's the value of numRows when that happens?

When I run Tester a window displays and I input a number. In this instance I did 3. Then I select OK which runs the InsertRow code and that's when it fails. The number could be any number based on user input.
Would you like continue this discussion in chat.

I was passing incorrect variable which was the reason it was not working correctly.  Here's the line of code that has been updated...
If IsNumeric(runmacro) Then vdc_InsertRow_Invent CLng(runmacro)
Thank you @Tim for seeing this through with me.  Much appreciated.

Can you edit this answer to explain what you changed? It's great that it worked, but other ppl won't learn much from this alone.

My posted code works as-is.  OP had made an error translating it into their workbook. See OP's second comment above: problem was runmacro vs. numrow.

You should turn off screen updating during the process:
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
.
. your code
.
.
.
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
